# chmod og-rwx server.key in windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create a certificate to PostgreSQL.

On [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ssl-tcp.html) the last step is use the command:

```
chmod og-rwx server.key
```

But I have Windows 10. What could be the equivalent of that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work, `icacls server.key /grant Everyone:F`

Explanation: So, what chmod does is change a file(s) permissions. The root, or whoever has the ability to chmod, can allow or remove permissions such as **r**eading a file, **w**riting to a file, or e**x**ecuting a file.
So the statement, **chmod og-rwx server.key** means **o** allow users who are not owners of this file, AND **g**, users who are part of this files' group to **rwx** (or read, write, and execute). Now, tell chmod what file we are doing this to? **server.key**.

The question then becomes, how do we replicate this command and options in windows 10? according to microsoft's technet page: `icacls` is the command to use. Next, mirror the options described by chmod..so we grant everyone full access.

Hope this helps (and more importantly works!)

Comment: This answer obviously has good interntions, but is actually the exact opposite of the linux command `chmod og-rwx server.key`. The command in this answer gives `Full control` to `Everyone` (which can have security implications), whereas the linux command recommended in PostgreSQL documentation denies all access to everyone, but the owner of the file.

Answer (score 1):

## Correct answer:

The most close equivalent of `chmod og-rwx server.key` in Windows 10 is:

```bash
icacls server.key /reset
icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"
```

*Note that the `icacls` command is also available in Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Vista and newer, but is not available in Windows XP.*

### The Linux command:

The `chmod og-rwx server.key` command mentioned in PostgreSQL documentation is using the [symbolic mode of `chmod`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Symbolic_modes):

According to the [main page of chmod](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) the format of symbolic mode is `[ugoa...][[-+=][perms...]...]`.

In the command above **letters `og`** mean "**Change access of all other users and groups except for the owner of the file**".

The **minus sign (`-`)** after `og` is an operator and means "**Remove the specified rights from the file**".

So `chmod og-rwx server.key` effectively removes read, write and execute permissions (`rwx`) to the `server.key` file for all users except for the owner.

### The Windows command:

The Windows command `icacls server.key /reset` **removes explicitly set permissions** on the file **leaving only inherited permissions**.

The command `icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"` gives **full control only to the owner** of the file and **removes inherited permissions for all users/groups**.

It accomplishes that with the:

- `/inheritance:r` option, which removes all permissions inherited from parent directories;
- `/grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"` option, which replaces explicit permissions for the owner with `Full control` (`F` stands for `Full control`).

Better explanations for these options can be found in the help of the `icacls` command:

```
PS> icacls /?
...
ICACLS name /reset [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    replaces ACLs with default inherited ACLs for all matching files.
...
/grant[:r] Sid:perm grants the specified user access rights. With :r,
    the permissions replace any previously granted explicit permissions.
    Without :r, the permissions are added to any previously granted
    explicit permissions.
...
/inheritance:e|d|r
    e - enables inheritance
    d - disables inheritance and copy the ACEs
    r - remove all inherited ACEs
...
```

### Hint

Just for completeness you could achieve the same thing with the Windows GUI.

Proper permissions for a `server.key` file in Windows would look like that:

[image: Proper permissions for a <code>server.key</code> file in Windows]

Before using this command, make sure that the owner of the file is set to the service account that is running the PostgreSQL server or the service won't be able to read the file.